# suggestion on implementing high performance assembly instructions generator

Tags: performance, assembly, generator, auto

I'm trying write a assembly instruction generator for one operation of a math library. To achieve high performance some operations are needed wrote in assembly language, and vectorization is also necessary. The final goal is to implement a cross-platform generator to automatically generate high performance assembly implementation to save time. For now the abstraction of computation operations is manually, I'm wonder if there are some more automatical way to abstract this operations. Maybe some techs of front-end of compiling will be applicable?

Comment: Your are describing a (high quality) compiler.

Comment: You can rarely achieve cross-platform high-performance assembly starting already from lower level abstraction, the math operation in it's source form should be abstract enough (like maybe C source) to allow for completely different breakdown for different platforms (for example AVX512 vs only SSE2 x86 CPU, etc...). Also I would suggest to do some prototyping first, to see if you can even beat modern (C++) compiler first, because you may actually not (within reasonable timeframe), or the gain may be negligible. Or if you manage to gain a lot, you may fill up missed-optimization bug to CC vendor

Comment: @Ped7g yes, your words make sense,  actually I have already wrote a version of assembly that can outperforms that generated by compiler, Well I'm just thinking maybe I can do better to optimize this operation by tuning some parameter of  my code like the loop unroll times,  etc.. so auto-generation maybe a good choice. Well I just want this process to be "smarter".

Comment: Then maybe post here question with example of such "outperforming" case, because that's not very likely. I'm not talking about marginal gains like couple of %, and if those are worth for your task, then that makes your effort still valid, I'm talking about bigger gains, which are unlikely (enough to ask you for example) with modern compilers, those are often result of wrong compiler configuration, or the source needs just a bit of hand-holding to navigate compiler toward more optimal results. While I personally love assembly, in real world projects it should take extra consideration to go ASM.

Comment: Normally getting big gains from assembly involves instruction sequences that a compiler doesn't generate, such as taking advantage of near parallel operations with the X86 xmm or ymm registers, for example this [assembly code for crc16/crc32](https://github.com/01org/isa-l/blob/master/crc/crc16_t10dif_01.asm).

Comment: Sometimes extensions are made to a language, such as system specific extensions to Fortran on some supercomputers (like a Cray) to take advantage of vectorized operations and/or parallel loops. I'm not aware of any extensions like these for C++.